# Ошибка при авторизации пользователей

Tags: php, авторизация, mysql

Делаю авторизацию пользователей и не могу понять, в чем ошибка? Переписывал код сотню раз - постоянно одна и та же ошибка - Неверный логин или пароль, хотя все верно!

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("iv-data") or die(mysql_error());

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $user_login = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["user_login"])));
        $user_password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5(md5(trim($_POST["user_password"]))));

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_login='$user_login'");
        $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        if($user_data["user_password"] == $user_password){
            echo "Вы вошли";
        }else{
            echo "Неверный логин или пароль";
        }
    print_r($user_data);
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user_login">
    <input type="password" name="user_password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Проверяйте что находится в переменной и ячейке массива при сравнении, отсюда и делайте вывод где ошибка.

PS. И еще: зачем вы вытаскиваете из базы данных всё, когда вам нужен только пароль?

Comment: Запрос изменил, пересмотрел - вроде все верно...

Comment: Что значит "код пересмотрел"? Результаты в студию:

    $user_password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5(md5(trim($_POST["user_password"]))));
    print_r( $user_password );
    /* ... */
    $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    print_r( $user_data );

Comment: И ещё - меня чисто интуитивно смущает это:
    
    $user_login = strtolower(...)

При правильной архитектуре этого быть не должно, а должно быть: 

    ...WHERE LOWER(user_login)=LOWER('$user_login')

(ну, если не придираться к отсутствию placeholders)

Comment: Спасибо, учту)

Вот результат ассоциативного массива: http://cs608826.vk.me/v608826628/ac29/7puU27szIiQ.jpg

Если отправляю пустые данные, то получается это: http://cs608826.vk.me/v608826628/ac30/Dnq7BXTe9MY.jpg

Comment: И что мы должны понять из этой мешанины? Ну её-богу, вы хоть немного потрудитесь самостоятельно, отформатируйте вывод, подумайте головой...

Comment: @Quell, сделайте пока что регистрацию без md5, успеете еще добавить. После выполнения запроса и создания ассоциативного массива напишите:

    echo 'Введенный пароль: ' . $user_password . '. Пароль из базы: ' . $user_data["user_password"];
    exit;

и покажите результат

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Проверьте какая длина строки в поле user_password в БД. Судя по скриншоту там 25 символов и часть хеша обрезается при сохранении в базу. Нужно поставить VARCHAR(32)